# three.js no object shown inside the container

Tags: three.js

I'm using the following code to start up learning three.js. This code is supposed to show a red sphere inside the black container but it does not for me. Is here anyone familiar with three.js to point out what is wrong with the code?

```
// Set the scene size.
const WIDTH = 400;
const HEIGHT = 300;

// Set some camera attributes.
const VIEW_ANGLE = 45;
const ASPECT = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
const NEAR = 0.1;
const FAR = 10000;

// Get the DOM element to attach to
const container =
    document.querySelector('#container');

// Create a WebGL renderer, camera
// and a scene
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
const camera =
    new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
        VIEW_ANGLE,
        ASPECT,
        NEAR,
        FAR
    );

const scene = new THREE.Scene();

// Add the camera to the scene.
scene.add(camera);

// Start the renderer.
renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

// Attach the renderer-supplied
// DOM element.
container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// Set up the sphere vars
const RADIUS = 50;
const SEGMENTS = 16;
const RINGS = 16;

// create the sphere's material
const sphereMaterial = 
  new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial(
    {
        color: 0xCC0000
    });

// Create a new mesh with
// sphere geometry
const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.SphereGeometry(
    RADIUS,
    SEGMENTS,
    RINGS),
  sphereMaterial);

// Move the Sphere back in Z so we
// can see it.
sphere.position.z = -300;

// Finally, add the sphere to the scene.
scene.add(sphere);
```

Comment: where and when do you call `renderer.render(scene, camera)`?

Comment: Never in the code above. But when I add renderer.render(scene, camera) to the end of the code, nothing changes. Still just a black container area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using `THREE.MeshLambertMaterial()` you won't see the object with this material until you add a light source into the scene.

For example, `THREE.DirectionalLight()`:

```
var dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
dirLight.position.set(100, 100, 100);
scene.add(dirLight);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/k6L14zh6/) example r86

Comment: thanks a lot! Can you recommend a book or any other source of three.js documentation?

Comment: :) All my knowledge is based on the trial and error method, surfing the Internet and reading many different sources about three.js. Unfortunately, the official documentation has no mention abou light sources when you use materials like Lambert, Phong or Standard (and their extensions).